Thevenin equivalent voltage of an AC source circuit

In the given circuit, I can't understand how voltage division is performed to find voltage across 5 ohm resistance.
I have already solved the problem by another method, I just want to know how voltage division has been used.

I don't know where the 8 comes from. It's a bit mysterious to me. You will have to look at the textbook and/or lecture notes to help me there. Perhaps someone else sees where the 8 comes in. But their result is correct. It's just weird to me. I would see $\frac{10}{\sqrt{2}}$ for the RMS voltage. Then $\frac{15}{10+15}$ as a divider. Then finally $\frac{5}{5+26}$ as the last divider. That gets to the same place. But the 8, and their splitting of 25 into 5*5 just seems mysterious. Your question is good. I must be blind to something important. So I'll +1 the question.

It looks like they developed it like this:$$\overbrace{\frac{10:\text{V}}{\sqrt{2}}}^{\text{RMS}}\cdot\frac{8}{\sqrt{10:\Omega+ 15:\Omega}\cdot\left[5:\Omega+20:\Omega+\left(10:\Omega,\vert\vert, 15:\Omega\right)\right]}\cdot\frac{15:\Omega}{8\sqrt{10:\Omega+ 15:\Omega}}\cdot 5:\Omega$$Which is the same as:$$\overbrace{\frac{10:\text{V}}{\sqrt{2}}}^{\text{RMS}}\cdot\frac{15:\Omega}{10:\Omega+15:\Omega}\cdot\frac{5:\Omega}{5:\Omega+20:\Omega+\left(10:\Omega,\vert\vert, 15:\Omega\right)}$$Which is how I see the dividers. I've no idea why the author wrote as they did.

I do not see any voltage divide equation. All I see is the equation for parallel connected resistors:
\$Req = \frac{R_1 * R_2}{R_1 + R_2}\$.
This equation was used two times. Frist one is for \$10\Omega\$ and \$15\Omega\$ (first didiver \$R_{12}\$).
And the second time for \$5\Omega\$ and \$R_{12}\$ in series with \$20\Omega\$.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
